# MATLAB - Search and get access of single entrys in Time Series Objects

Tags: matlab, time-series

I want to have a for-loop, which goes through each entry in a Time Series Object. 
Below are the properties of my `timeseriesobject`, filename:`ts`.

> Common Properties:
>               Name: 'unnamed'
>               Time: [70001x1 double]
>           TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
>               Data: [70001x1 double]
>           DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]

How can I easily go through each time value pair inside a for-loop. I want to have access to the data value and to the time value, so that I can temporarily store it for calculations. I didn't find the exact syntax in the documentation to do this. Hope you can me help out!

*For example/ what I'm looking for written in pseudo-code!*

```
dataValue = ts(22).data    (comment: data value from entry #22 of Time Series Object ts)  
TimeValue = ts(22).time    (comment: time value from entry #22 of Time Series Object ts)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example along with what you have tried and why it did not provide what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time series objects are to be used *per se*. No need to store them nor their content in some other variables.

For example

```
x = rand(5,1);
ts = timeseries(x)

D = ts.data;
T = ts.time;
```

`D` and `T` are plain vectors and can be accessed by `D(3)` or `ts.data(3)`.

Comment: ts.data(3) that is what I was looking for.Thanks!